# Sandcastle: Any way to show inherited members without showing base class?

Tags: documentation, sandcastle

Given a derived class (using C#):

```
public class BaseClass {
   public void AMethod() {}
}
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
}
```

and running a Sandcastle documentation project in which `BaseClass` is hidden (Sandcastle Visibility's API filters),

Is there any way to document the `DerivedClass` members that are inherited from `BaseClass` as if they were declared explicitly?

I do not want to make wrappers:

```
public class BaseClass {
   public void AMethod() {}
}
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
   new public void AMethod() { base.AMethod(); }
}
```

^^^ I DON'T WANT TO DO THIS.

These Stack Overflow entries are similar but not what I seek:

- [Hide methods inherited from Object from Sandcastle-generated documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666123/hide-methods-inherited-from-object-from-sandcastle-generated-documentation)

I want to show rather than hide.

- [How should I document a inherited members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536169/how-should-i-document-a-inherited-members)

The application eschews, explicitly, interfaces or contracts because of a legacy issue with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.

Thanks!